# Styling React JS

Tags: reactjs, react-native, styles

I want to create a component that I can pass a prop which can change the styles of that Components. Just like **Block Component** in some **React Native Theme**.

Example:
`<Block gray></Block>`

That will change the background color to gray something.

I'm a beginner sorry :D

Comment: For quick styling, You need to use any frontend UI framework like bootstrap, material-ui etc. Then you can just use style classes in you components

Comment: Can you add more details to your question? What do you exactly want? Like you want to create custom styles and pass it as a props ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are a beginner then I would highly recommend learning the **React styling and CSS.**
because of there are showing some easy tricks with the example to understand react styling

doc's link:https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html

For Example:

**How do I add CSS style to components? Pass a string as the  prop:**

```
render() {
  return <Block style={{backgroundColor:'grey'}}>Menu</Block>
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. There are no hyphens for inline styling. It should be `style={{backgroundColor:'grey'}}`

Answer (score -2):

If you're just looking for simple easily styleable components, then I would recommend react-bootstrap. They have plenty of documentation to explain how to pass the props that would make a grey component.

Link: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/